# How can i visualize a customer journey with tag manager and google data studio?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a website where the customer can take a quiz to find the right products. I want to track the customer's journey on the quiz, to see what they choose and where people fall off.

The quiz starts at example.com/start/ and for every step they take, the URL "expand" to e.g. example.com/start/first_step/, next step example.com/start/first_step/second_step etc.

I think I can do it with tag manager, by creating events for each step / URL. But my first issue is, that the events get to long. The other issue is, I cant figure out how to visualize the journey in either Google analytics 4 or Google data studio.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5qmH.png)

Does any of you have a great idea for how I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what exactly to you mean saying "the events get to long"? Do you mean the requests payload to the google analytics server?

Generally speaking, I'd recommend the following:

1. Create a generic event for all quiz steps
2. Add two parameter for the progress, one containing the steps name an one containing the index (e.g. "quiz_step_str" & "quiz_step_index")
3. Send the events to GA4
4. Visualize them using a bar chart. (https://analyticsdemystified.com/google-analytics/step-step-guide-creating-funnels-googles-data-studio/)

Additional information regarding step 2:
The parameter containing the step name can be generated using js and getting the value from the url. Just scrape the corrsponding part from it (e.g. "example.com/start/first_step/" -> "first_step").
For the parameter containing the steps' index, I recommend creating a lookup table.

Comment: Thank you for your help. When you say generic event, is that like I've done (See the screenshot). No I just mean that the length (Characters) of the events has some kind of maximum, so when i try to create an event from URL, it shortens it in Google analytics

Comment: Im not sure what you mean in step 2, one containing the step name - should i just withdraw that from the URL as you write in additional information? The one containing the index, Im not sure what you mean?

Comment: With generic event, I mean you name the event "quiz_event" and populate the mentioned parameters with information on the funnel step

Comment: With Index, I mean the number of the step as a integer. 
For example, on the first step, this is what the event would look like:

Event name: "quiz_event"
quiz_step_str: "first_step"
quiz_step_index: "1"

Comment: How can I add the index number automatically?

Comment: You can not. Just create a lookup table in GTM with page path as input and the index as the output. https://www.searchviu.com/en/lookup-tables-google-tag-manager/

e.g.: input:"/start/first_step/" output:1

For the visualization itself, the index parameter is not required. You don't have to use it, if you don't want to.

Comment: Thank you, one last question. How can I use the parameters I set in the events, in Google data studio?

Comment: In GA4 you have to set them as custom parameters under "configuration".
After reconnecting your GA4 data source in Data Studio, the paameters should appear as dimensions in the source.